# Concourse resources not working after changing instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, concourse, concourse-git-resource

I need some help to understand what is happening with our Concourse installation. We have Concourse working in an AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance (web and worker). For different reasons, we needed to move to a new EC2 instance. The problem is that Concourse running in this second instance doesn't have access to GitHub or S3 resources. The credentials for both are in the pipeline so I understand it's saved in the DB which is the same. What could be happening??

Github resource error:

```
resource script '/opt/resource/check []' failed: exit status 128

stderr:
Identity added: /tmp/git-resource-private-key (/tmp/git-resource-private- 
key)
Cloning into '/tmp/git-resource-repo-cache'...
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

S3 resource error:

```
resource script '/opt/resource/check []' failed: exit status 1

stderr:
[31merror listing files: RequestError: send request failed
caused by: Get https://s3.amazonaws.com/xxxx-bucket?marker=&prefix=pipeline-configurations%2Fmaven%2F: dial tcp: lookup s3.amazonaws.com on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:45952->[::1]:53: read: connection refused
[0m
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Exit status code `128` from git usually means that it's having connection problems and the logs from the S3 resource shows `connection refused`.

Looks like this new setup is having connectivity, instead of permission, issues.